# Using Euler's theorem to solve a question in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am supposed to find the smallest number $y \in N$, so that $a^y \equiv 1 \pmod{ 100}$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z$ with $\gcd (a, 100)=1$.

I thought I could use Euler's theorem, which states that $a^x ≡ 1 \pmod {100}$ (for all $a$ out of $\mathbb Z$)
where $x$ is the result one gets by plugging $m$ into Euler's totient function.

From a hint I got in reply to my previous question on this topic, I gathered that Euler's totient function does not (in all cases) guarantee the minimum value to fulfil the above equation.

So my question is, how I can find that minimal value in the concrete case noted above?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As in your prior question, see [the Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).   That article contains lists of the values, and a discussion on how to compute it.

Comment: Hi Lulu, thanks for your very helpful reply! I did not hear of the Carmichael function before, and it seems to provide exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where there is no primitive: the group of units $\mathbb Z_{100}^×\cong\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_{20} $ isn't cyclic.

We can see though that in this case the answer is $20$.

(This result relies on the fact that the group of units functor respects products.)

---

In general,  you are looking for the exponent of the group of units,  which,  as @lulu notes, is precisely the Carmichael function,  $\lambda (n) $.

Comment: thanks for your answer! wouldn't we have to multiply 2 with 20 though, to get 40 as the result?

Comment: this was also the answer I figured by using the Carmichael function, cause using the prime factorization of 100 (2^2*5^2), I calculated C(4)=2 and C(5^2)=20 and by using the multiplicity of the Carmichael function, I received 40 as an answer.

Comment: No it should be  $20$.  If it was $40$ the group of units would be cyclic.

Comment: The Carmichael function isn't multiplicative.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right. I forgot that the Carmichael function uses the least common multiple (lcm) of the prime factorization and not its product.

Comment: one more remark: the Carmichael function only gives the minimum exponent for those values of a that are between 1 and n (n being the modulo in question). However, the question I have to solve asks for a minimum solution for ALL a that are coprime to n. Does this limit the usability of the Carmichael function in this context or can that problem be remedied?

Comment: This works for _any_ $a $ coprime to $n $, since every such $a$ is in a (unique)  residue class in the group of units  $\mathbb Z_n^×$, and the result applies to the entire group.

Comment: Let me amend my answer.  Actually it's a result about the number  $100$.  We have $\lambda (100)=20$.  That means  $20$ is the least exponent $m $ such that for _all_ $a $ with $(a,100)=1$, that $a^m\equiv1\pmod {100} $.

Comment: ok, thanks! I understand this now.

Comment: You bet.  As an example,  since  $(103,100)=1$, we can conclude that  $103^{20}\equiv1\pmod {100} $.